# Details about StreamWriter

Tags: c#, winforms, streamwriter

Does StreamWriter or StreamReader auto creates the file when is using like below?

```
   StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("foo");
```

Comment: There are no parameterless constructors for `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`. It would have been worth you checking your sample _at least compiled_ before asking the question.

Comment: I miss-typed the parameter ... Anyway thanks for down vote .. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it creates the file if it doesn't exist, as per [the documentation for this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx):

> The path parameter can be a file name, including a file on a Universal
>   Naming Convention (UNC) share. If the file exists, it is overwritten;
>   otherwise, a new file is created.

Answer (score 2):

Certain forms of the constructor can overwrite, append, or create a new file yes.  Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx for more details.